# Does ES6 introduce a mechanism to make block-scoped function statements (not expressions)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Does ES6 introduce a mechanism to make block-scoped function statements (not expressions)?

The following is illegal in ES5 and I presume remains so in ES6?

```
!function() { 
  'use strict'; 
  { 
    function foo () { 
      console.log('foo!'); 
    }
  } 
  foo(); 
}();
```

Edit: corrected nomenclature.

Comment: You seem to be contradicting yourself. You say that this would be illegal in ES5 because of the block-scoped function, but then ask if a block-scoped function is introduced in ES6. Or do you mean to say something different?

Comment: i think declarations are like var, not let. i also don't think es6 has blocks, except loops and stuff..

Comment: @dandavis it does have blocks for `let` https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=true&spec=false&playground=true&code=function%20foo()%20%7B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20a%20%3D%20123%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20console.log(a)%0A%7D%0A%0Afoo()

Comment: @zerkms: whoa, indeed it does (http://www.es6fiddle.net/i87rwnp7/). i guess that's backwards-compat since you need the `let` keyword to get the special behavior...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Your code is *syntactically* valid and "legal" in ES6.</s>

It wouldn't work as "expected" though: functions even in ES6 are scoped by the enclosing function (or by nothing if run in a global scope).

You can declare it using block(real block!)-scope visibility with `let` though:

```
function bar() {
  {
    let foo = function() {};
    foo(); // foo is defined
  }

  foo(); // foo is not defined
}

bar();
```

[Demo on babeljs.io](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=true&spec=false&playground=true&code=function%20bar()%20%7B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20foo%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20foo()%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20foo()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Abar()%3B)

Comment: not sure if OP will consider function expressions function statements (same?), but you make clear the only way to get the scope he asked for.

Comment: @dandavis at least now they have choice :-)

Comment: @zerkms: No, OPs code is neither syntactically valid nor legal in ES6. What makes you think that?

Comment: @Bergi I don't see anything there that makes the code *syntactically* invalid

Comment: Oh dang, are they now? […re-reading the spec…] Wait - [are function declarations in block statements lexically scoped now?!](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-blockdeclarationinstantiation)

Comment: @Bergi seems like I underestimated complexity of the question, hence crossed my wrong statement about syntax correctness :-)

Comment: So did I. From what I've read, it seems they actually are valid now…

Comment: @Bergi: Correct:  `StatementListItem[Yield, Return] : Statement[?Yield, ?Return] Declaration[?Yield]`. `Declaration`s are allowed inside blocks, which includes function declarations.

Comment: @Felix, so `'use strict'; {  function foo() {} } foo(); // undefined is not a function`?

Comment: @Ben: Uhm, I'm not sure. I was only referring to the fact that the *syntax* is allowed now, not how it's going to be evaluated. Don't have much time to dig very deep into the spec, but this is relevant: https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-block-level-function-declarations-web-legacy-compatibility-semantics.